# Scraping usando Selenium e Beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

Estou tentando fazer um scrap em um blog de livros, preciso pegar os títulos e as categorias de todos os livros postados. Na primeira tentativa, obtive um Attribute Error, o que deve acontecer várias vezes pois o site é mal feito e nem sempre as coisas que eu to pegando vão estar com o mesmo código. Para tentar lidar com isso eu adicionei um `except` para que o looping continue. Segue meu código até agora:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = '/home/porco/Downloads/chromedriver')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors') 
options.add_argument('--test-type')
options.binary_location='/usr/bin/chromium' 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

url = 'http://amoraosromances.blogspot.com/'
driver.get(url)

A = []
B = []

while True: 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

    try:
        for div in soup.findAll('div', class_='post hentry'):
            titulo = div.find('h3', class_='post-title entry-title')
            A.append(titulo.text.strip().title())
            temas = div.find('span', class_='post-labels')
            B.append(temas.text.strip().replace('\n', ' ').replace('Marcadores:', '').title())

            print(titulo.txt)
            print('...rodando...')
    except AttributeError:
        continue 
    try:
        nextButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Blog1_blog-pager-older-link"]')
        nextButton.click()  
    except: 
        break

print('...fazendo .csv e json...') 
df=pd.DataFrame(A, columns=['Título'])
df['Tema'] = B
df

df.to_csv('autor-tema2.csv')
df.to_json('autor-tema2.json', orient='records')

driver.quit()
```

Eu tenho duas dúvidas, sendo uma relacionada ao que falei lá em cima do `except`, não tenho certeza se está funcionando pois está rodando faz um tempo aqui e a url parou de mudar. Tem como eu adicionar alguma coisa para que possam ter umas saídas para eu ver em que fase do processo está? Coloquei uns `print()`, mas não se mostraram muito uteis.

A outra dúvida é se tem como impedir que o navegador abra novas janelas/abas, pois este site tem muita propaganda e acredito que meu computador pode travar no meio do processo se essa janelas ficarem abrindo, são cerca de 3.057 posts. Se não tiver como impedir, uma maneira de serem fechadas logo que abrem seria bom também.

Abraços.

Answer (score -1):

Para log você pode utilizar o logger, é melhor que o print para este caso.

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
self.logger.warning('Aqui você coloca o texto do log')
```